# Combined "if" and "while", how to break out of all nested-loops when "if" condition fulfilled?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, nested-loops, break

How can I write Python script to combine `while`s with `if`s and `break` entire nested-loop if condition met?
I have read other topics, but I cannot get script working...

How can I wrote this script to exit or break all nested-loops, when `if` condition is met?

**Script:**

```
breaker = False
while True:
  ...commands...
  if ... :
    ...commands...
    if ... :
      ...commands...
      while True:
        ...commands...
        if ... :
          if ... :
            breaker = True
            break # ...to exit all loops
        i += 1
   j -= 1
if breaker:
  break

...continue script here if `break`
```

Comment: Put all of this in a function and do `return`.

Comment: Or even in *multiple* functions. Code nested this heavily is hard to read or reason about.

Comment: If I will write this with Function and Return, will that work properly?

Answer (score 0):

For each if statement you need to close it with an else each one need to have one otherwise I don't think the code will work and that last (j-=1) I think it has to be on top of the last (if breaker:) code you made.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your problem is a bad source code design (a 'bad smell' as described in https://refactoring.guru/smells/long-method). As a rule of thumb: do not use more than one / two nested conditionals in a function (i.e. `while`, `if`, `until`, ...). Try to refactor your code as e.g. shown in Martin Fowler's Book (https://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html) or in many good tutorials (e.g. https://refactoring.guru/extract-method).

You will see that this will simplify your life - and you can use a `return` from a function instead of some break statement.

Answer (score 0):

I also agree with @pedro echavarria that you need to close it with an else: - it also needs something like :

```
else:
    variable = False
```

to exit the while loops.